# How do you prove 2 normal random variables X and Y are jointly normally distributed?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

How do you prove 2 normal random variables X and Y are jointly normally distributed? I know that any linear sum of X and Y should be normally distributed but how do you prove that?

Comment: Please put your question in the body of the post. It is not considered good practice to have the question only in the title. There are also some people who will vote to close your question unless you show what you've tried already.

Comment: What _else_ do you know about $X$ and $Y$ other than that they are individually normally distributed? I am assuming that you know the means and variances of $X$ and $Y$; and am asking what _else_ do you know about them.

Comment: Yes the means and variances are known. I would like to know the answer when this is the only information available.

Answer (score 1):

If you know $X$ is normally distributed and $Y$ is normally distributed, and nothing else is known, then it is not possible to prove that the pair $(X, Y)$ are jointly normally distributed, due to the existence of [pathological examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Two_normally_distributed_random_variables_need_not_be_jointly_bivariate_normal).

One simple way to demonstrate that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal is to find another pair $(U,V)$  of **independent** normal variables such that $X$ and $Y$ are each a linear combination of $(U,V)$, i.e.,
$$\begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}U\\V\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}e\\f\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some constants $a,b,c,d,e,f$. Depending on the author, this is either a definition or a result that requires proof. If it requires proof, a common approach is to use moment-generating functions.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the informative answer!